# Процедура возвращает пустую матрицу

Tags: функции, pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

Есть модуль с процедурами. Функция *MultXSq* работает странно. Внутри процедуры сохраняет значения в итоговую матрицу, есть вывод внутри и все хорошо. Но по запросу вывода этой самой матрицы с результатом возвращается матрица с нулями.

Программа

```
uses UnitArray.

UnitArray in 'UnitArray.pas';

var
  masX1: TMatrix;
  masX2: TMatrix;
  masXRez: TMatrix;

begin
  AddRandomData(masX1);
  AddRandomData(masX2);
  print(masX1);
  writeln;
  print(masX2);

  MultXSq(masX1, masX2, masXRez); //умножение матриц, внутри процедуры матрица Z (третья) содержит значения
  writeln;
  print(masXRez); //уже пусто???
end.
```

Модуль

```
unit UnitArray;

interface

Const N = 3;
  M = 3;
Type TVector = array[1..N] of integer;
  TMatrix = array[1..M] of TVector;
Procedure AddRandomData(var X:TMatrix);
Procedure Print(const X:TMatrix);
Procedure MultXSq(var X:TMatrix; Y:TMatrix; Z:TMatrix);

implementation

 procedure Print(const X:Tmatrix); //вывод матрицы на экран
 var i,j:integer;
 begin
   for i := 1 to M do
   begin
     for j := 1 to N do 
       write(X[i,j]:3);
     writeln;
   end;
 end;

procedure AddRandomData(var X:TMatrix); //рандомим значения матрицы
 var i,j:integer;
 begin
  // randomize;
   for i := 1 to M do
     for j := 1 to N do
       X[i,j] := random(10);
 end;

Procedure MultXSq(var X:TMatrix; Y:TMatrix; Z:TMatrix);
var i,j,j2,sum: integer;
begin
  writeln;
  sum := 0;
  for i := 1 to M do
  begin
    for j2 := 1 to M do
    begin
      for j := 1 to M do
        sum := sum + X[i,j] * Y[j,j2];
    Z[i,j2] := sum; //сохраняем значение
    sum := 0;
    end;
 end;
writeln(Z); //вот тут выводится матрица нормально
end;

initialization
finalization
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так вы же копию передаёте:

```pascal
Procedure MultXSq(var X:TMatrix; Y:TMatrix; Z:TMatrix);
```

Передавайте все параметры по ссылке:

```pascal
PROCEDURE MultXSq(VAR X, Y, Z: TMatrix);
```